# NODE ¿Como cargar el contenido de un archivo properties una unica vez?

Tags: nodejs, variables-globales

soy nuevo acá y quiero preguntar algo que no logré encontrar como respuesta en la web. Perdón porque se que es muy básico lo que voy a preguntar:

Estoy aprendiendo NODE, estoy haciendo algo donde los textos que respondo ante errores o validaciones se encuentran insertos en el código NODE, entonces mi idea es generar un archivo app.properties con el siguiente contenido por ejemplo:

```
teamsListed='Teams listed.'
teamListed='Team listed.'
teamNotFound='Team not found.'
```

donde los textos no queden harcode en el código NODE, sino que sean parametrizables en un solo lugar.

Luego en mi archivo principal index.ts definí lo siguiente:

```
import PropertiesReader from 'properties-reader';
const properties = PropertiesReader('./app.properties');
```

Y lo utilizo de esta forma:

```
res.status(200).json({ message: this.properties.get('teamsListed'), teams })
```

Mi pregunta es:
Donde debo guardar el contenido de la constante properties para poder accederla desde otras clases como controllers, etc. Ya que si hago esta misma definición de la constante en cada modulo que utilizo estaría leyendo el archivo app.properties muchas veces, y solo quiero leerlo una vez al inicio y dejarlo disponible para todo el resto de los modulos.

Pense que podía guardarlo en globals, no se si es posible y es una buena solución.
Me ayudarían con alguna idea de como sería una solución profesional a esta necesidad?

Gracias!!!

Answer (score 0):

En [NodeJS](https://nodejs.org/) puedes hacer uso del objeto [`global`](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_global).

De esta forma cualquier variable que declares como propiedad del objeto `global` estará disponible en todos tus módulos sin que tengas que importar nada en ellos, excepto la primera importación, necesaria para establecer la variable global.

Supongamos que el punto de entrada de tu aplicación Node es `index.js`, entonces, lo que debes hacer es importar tus propiedades tal como lo hace actualmente y establecer su valor a una propiedad del objeto `global`. Por ejemplo:

```js
// index.js (punto de entrada de la aplicación)
import PropertiesReader from 'properties-reader';
global.properties = PropertiesReader('./app.properties');
```

Ahora, tu variable `properties` es parte del objeto `global`, por lo tanto podemos usarlo en cualquier parte de nuestra aplicación, en cualquier módulo, simplemente llamando a su valor.

Por ejemplo:

```js
res.status(200).json({ message: properties.get('teamsListed'), teams });
```

Como puedes observar no necesito declarar `global` solo uso directamente el nombre de la variable.

Answer (score 0):

Muchas gracias Mauricio por tu ayuda. Se que era muy basica mi pregunta pero me ayudo mucho tu respuesta para seguir aprendiendo!

Comment: esto no es una respuesta. Es un comentario y en la respuesta de @Mauricio puedes añadir comentarios. Y si te sirvió marca su respuesta como acepta dando al check a la izquierda.